# SFSafariViewController - How long does the cache last?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

In my application, it opens a website using SFSafariViewController. I don't want user to always login when opening the website. And I didn't find any documentation about SFSafariViewController cache.

So how long does SFSafariViewController cache last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SFSafariViewController` use the standard iOS web view cache, which is managed by the system.

The duration for which items are stored in the cache is determined by the cache's eviction policy, which is based on a combination of the amount of storage space available and the age of the items in the cache.

So `SFSafariViewController` does'nt have its own cache and does not provide any APIs for managing the cache.

Use `WKWebView` instead, it will store cache